# Tesseract whitelist is not accepting special characters

Tags: character, tesseract, whitelist

I'm using Tesseract (version 5.3.1) in Windows to recognize characters from a text that includes *special characters* like ñüá. Most of these characters are within the Latin script, so I've declared this in the command line.

In this image, the special characters are ñ,Ñ,á,é.

[image: Example of the text]

The command line I'm using is

```
 tesseract text.png stdout --psm 6 -l Latin -c tessedit_char_whitelist=aáeéiocfhklmnñtÑ
```

However, the output text is missing white spaces between words, and the special characters are being completely ignored, resulting in:

```
aoloaalcalmoo
okonioniachillalif
```

Do you know why tesseract is not taking into account the characters I've declared in the whitelist? Maybe I'm not correctly specifying the special characters

Any help is greatly appreciated.